# LWUIT HtmlComponent out of memory exception

Tags: java-me, lwuit

i want to display an image and Description from Rss File on LWUIT Form Screen
here my Code:

```
HTMLComponent com=new HTMLComponent();
com.setBodyText(detailNews.getDescription());
form2.addComponent(com);
```

**In place of** **detailNews.getDescription()**,the string coming form an Rss URL in a loop is

```
<p><img border="1" align="left" width="150" vspace="2" hspace="2" height="159" src="/tmdbuserfiles/Prithvi2_launch1(3).jpg" alt="Prithvi II, ballistic missile, DRDO, armed forces,Chandipur, Balasore district, Odisha State" />The Strategic Forces 
Command of the armed forces successfully flight-tested the surface-to-surface Prithvi II missile from Chandipur in Balasore </P>
```

if i execute, i am facing the application has unexpectedly quit because ,it ran out of memory exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to show the image, remove the `img` tag from the html string.

```
String description = detailNews.getDescription();
StringBuffer newDescription = new StringBuffer();
int imgIndex = description.indexOf("<img");

newDescription.append(description.substring(0, imgIndex));
imgIndex = description.indexOf(">", imgIndex + 1);
newDescription.append(description.substring(imgIndex + 1));
description = newDescription.toString();
com.setBodyText(description);
```

Comment: i am reading 4 Rss files and displaying on my Form with tabs, i am able to read 4 files and successfully displayed titles and images (Note:images are displayed using ListCellrenderer),but when i click on list item ,i need to display the description,but i am facing outof memory exception again and my application is getting closed?

Comment: You might be creating too much objects to treat the click event. But I think this is subject to another question...

Comment: now i tested again,even i am not able to display titles also,in the middle itself,it is throwing the outofmemory exception

Comment: Hi,can you give your email id